# Players $A, B$ are gamblers, B rolls the cube. A is a cheater, he rolled his cube again and again till he get an equal or higher number than $B$.

Tags: probability

Players $A, B$ are gamblers, B rolls the cube.

A is a cheater, he rolled his cube again and again till he get an equal or higher number than $B$.

Given that $A$ rolled his cube twice., find the probability that $B$ gets the number $4$.

I will be grateful for an explanation why I just cant calculate this like that:

I know that $A$ rolled his cube twice he get a lower number than 4 , and a equal\higher number than 4.

The probability is $\frac{3}{6}\cdot \frac{3}{6}=\frac{1}{4}.$

The probabibility that $B$ got $4$ is  $\frac{1}{6}$.

Then the answer is $\frac{\frac{1}{6}}{\frac{1}{4}}$

**I know my solution is wrong but I can't get why.**

Thanks!

Comment: When you say that $A$ rolled his cube twice, do you mean he rolled it once and got below B, then on the second time he got equal or higher? Also when you say cube is it equivalent to a dice?

Comment: Yes , @Caedmonc

Comment: Your $1/4$ value is representing the wrong thing. That is the probability that GIVEN $B$ got a 4, $A$ would roll exactly twice. Also the probability that B got a 4 is definitely not $1/6$, since the fact that $A$ rolled twice completely changes that.

Comment: For example, note that the (posterior) probability that $B$ got a $6$ is $0$.  After all, if $B$ had a $6$, $A$ could never get a higher roll, no matter how many trials.

Comment: @lulu A tie is sufficient for $A$. However, if $B$ throws a $1$, the probability is actually $0$, since $A$ has at least a tie sure anyway without repeating the throw.

Comment: @Peter Ah, I read it as a "higher roll".  Yes, you are correct.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I will refer to two events as $A$ and $B$ and refer to person $B$ as person $1$ and $A$ as person $2$.

If you are applying Bayes' theorem to find posterior probability of an event, first check what the event is and what the given condition is. The given condition in this case is that person $2$ had to roll twice to get a number equal to or more than person $1$. Say that event is $B$. If the event that person $1$ rolls *four* is $A$ then you are trying to find the probability $P(A\mid B)$. You need to first find $P(A \cap B)$ and $P(B)$. Please note that $P(B)$ is unconditional probability of person $2$ having to roll twice to get equal to or more than person $1$.

If person $1$ got *one*, there is no way person $2$ can roll less than that in the first roll. So there is no second roll required.

If person $1$ rolls *two*, probability that it takes a second roll for person $2$ to roll *two* or more,

$ \displaystyle \frac{1}{6} \cdot \frac{5}{6}$

Similarly if person $1$ rolls $3, ~$ it is
$ \displaystyle~ \frac{2}{6} \cdot \frac{4}{6}$

So if you add all cases and multiply by the probability of person $1$ rolling each number,

$ \displaystyle P(B) = \frac{1 \cdot 5 + 2 \cdot 4 + 3 \cdot 3 + 4 \cdot 2 + 5 \cdot 1}{6 \cdot 6 \cdot 6}$

Now what is $P(A \cap B)$? That is person $1$ rolls *four* and it takes a second roll for person $2$ to roll *four* or more.

Then finally, you can apply the formula $~P(A\mid B) = \dfrac{P(A\cap B)}{P(B)}$

Comment: I think you made a big mistake. Bayes' theorem does not require independence, but the Naïve Bayes' theorem or conditional probability formula most definitely does. You used the Naïve Bayes' theorem. We can prove these events are not independent since. Read this for the difference between the two: https://towardsdatascience.com/5-minute-machine-learning-naive-bayes-f48472670fdd

Comment: The events are independent if: $P(A|B) = P(A)$. Let event A be that player 2 rolls twice, and event B is that player 1 rolls a 1. The probability of A given B is 0, but $P(A) > 0$. This proves the events are not independent.

Comment: @Caedmon where am I saying events are independent?

Comment: You didn't say they are, but the formula you are using requires that the events are independent. The events are not independent, so that formula cannot be used.

Comment: @Caedmon I think you are misunderstanding the article you linked to. There it is about having multiple other events $B_i$, and needing those to be independent to use a simplified version of Bayes that combines those $B_i$. There is no need for $B$ to be independent from $A$.

Comment: @Caedmon there is no mistake in the work and if you want, I can explain. The formula is absolutely applicable for non-independent events. Conditional probability in general indicates that events are not independent. Before you read data science link, read this https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bayes%27_theorem

Comment: @Caedmon If the formula was applicable _only_ for independent events:  $P(A \cap B) = P(A) \cdot P(B)$ and then formula gives $P(A \mid B) = P(A)$ then why would anyone write that formula instead of just writing $P(A \mid B) = P(A)$? And it is no surprise we get $P(A)$ given events are independent.

Comment: @MathLover Huh, maybe you are right, but then why does it say in so many places that it requires independence?

Comment: @Caedmon please let me know where it says - any link... I can surely read through and comment. If $A$ and $B$ are independent events then the prior and posterior probability of $A$ remains the same so we do not need to apply any conditional probability formula.

Comment: @MathLover Yeah I agree with you that you are correct, it's just very odd then that the first link I sent you stated: "Well, you need to know that the distinction between Bayes theorem and Naive Bayes is that Naive Bayes assumes conditional independence where Bayes theorem does not. This means the relationship between all input features are independent. Maybe not a great assumption, but this is is why the algorithm is called “naive”." Odd

Comment: Sorry, I added an upvote because I agree with your logic. I'm kind of curious now, I can write a quick bit of code to test this over millions of runs, do you want to find the result from your formula and we quick compare?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/133165/discussion-between-math-lover-and-caedmon).

Comment: @Caedmon By "input features" that article means all the various events $B_i$ that cause us to re-evaluate the probability of $A$. It is not at all saying that $A$ and the $B_i$ need to be independent, only that IF the $B_i$ are independent of *each other* (or can be assumed to be so) then the formula for $P(A|B_1..B_n)$ simplifies nicely to a "naive" version.